# What is LOCAL=NO in oracle processes

Tags: oracle, bash, unix

I was trying to find out processes that are consuming more memory on my Unix box using `top` command:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
23421 test    18   0 6408m 2.8g 2.8g D  0.0 23.7   1:03.63 xyz     
11874 test    15   0 6378m 1.9g 1.9g S  0.0 16.1   0:05.47 xyz     
31217 test    15   0 6379m 1.9g 1.9g R  0.0 16.0   0:44.21 xyz
```

As above processes are consuming more than 15% of MEMory, I tried to search further:

```
-bash-3.2$ ps 23421 11874 31217 
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
23421 ?        Ds     1:03 ora_dbw0_xyz
11874 ?        Ss     0:05 oraclexyz (LOCAL=NO)
31217 ?        Ds     0:46 oraclexyz (LOCAL=NO)
```

This command shows some output that Oracle database is consuming more memory.
On searching in internet I found that ora_dbw0 is some database writer process but I am not able to understand what is (LOCAL=NO) process and how is it associated with Oracle database. Please help me in understanding what are these processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(LOCAL=NO) processes are the processes of connections using SQL*net (localhost or remote machines) and are not using MTS (Multi Threaded server)

local processes, connections from the database server, using ORACLE_SID use the Bequeath protocol. In the process list these are show as : 
oracledxxx (DESCRIPTION=(LOCAL=YES)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=beq)))